# htaccess redirects to subdomain: how to create links and images in HTML?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a domain named `domain.com`. I cannot change the document root, but the files for the webpage are in a subfolder named `folder`. When I access the url via a browser, I want the webpage to be loaded from the subfolder. Hence, I created the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ folder/$1 [PT,L]
```

Now I wanted to create an HTML page showing a simple image (`logo.png`), which is located in `folder` (path: `[document root]\folder\logo.png`). When I load the page in the browser, the image is not loaded. The HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="/logo.png">
```

Obviously, if I change the HTML to:

```
<img src="/folder/logo.png">
```

it works. However, I want to hide the existence of `folder` from the user.

Can this be done by changing my htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is only working for the landing page. Change your rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!folder/)(.*)$ folder/$1 [NC,PT,L]
```

Comment: great stuff, thanks. by the way, with this technique it is possible to redirect one domain (d1.com) to another domain (d2.com) without letting the user know anything about it (e.g. showing d2.com in some url). is this correct?

Comment: No redirection across the domain won't hide URL unless one uses proxy.